# Crossdomain Ajax call to Service isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP MVC and I'm trying to call a service that's on another one of my MVC websites.

I'm trying to use the following Ajax call.

```
function SomeFunction(decision) {
    if (decision == false)
        decision = "no";
    else
        decision = "yes";

    var input = {
        LogEventType:"PageView",                  
        CurrentPage: "invitation/?decision=" + decision + "&id=" + 32323,
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "https://somewebsite.com/api/ClickStream/LogWebEvent/",
        data: JSON.stringify(input),
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("We're awesome")
        },
        error: function () { console.log("Call to SomeFunction failed.") }
    });
}
```

I don't get any visible errors and I also put breakpoints on the service and inside of the success/error function of the ajax call but it never reaches any of them.

Anyone see where I messed up?

EDIT:
Here is the Web Apis function I'm trying to access

```
[ActionName("LogWebEvent")]
[HttpPost]
public void LogWebEvent(ClickStreamEventDto data)
{
    try
    {
        _clickstreamLogger.LogWebEvent(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Where ClickStreamEventDto is

```
public class ClickStreamEventDto: Analytics.IAnalyticEventDto
{
    public string LogEventType { get; set; }
    public string CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It never calls the service method. To make sure I put a breakpoint inside of the method while it was running in debug mode and it never reaches it.

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery JSONP? Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: Is `SomeFunction()` called at least?

Comment: Yes, SomeFunction is called. I've stepped through it in javascript debugger in Chrome.

Comment: Is you Jsonp response wrapped in you callback to SomeFunction()?

Comment: @EduardoQuintana what do you mean? A buttons onClick event calls SomeFunction

Comment: Oh ok, i was asking because jsonp sends the respond to the client wrapped in a callback i didn't saw that everything was on SomeFunction my bad.

Comment: Can you confirm/have you tested that an Ajax call that expects a response of JsonP is capable of handling calling a method whose return type is void?

Comment: There's so much wrong with this ajax request. JSONP can't be post. The header you are setting is a response header, not a request header. the crossDomain option is irrelevant. contentType is ignored for jsonp requests. Pick either CORS or JSONP, you can't do both.

Comment: @Flater I have not thought about that.

Comment: @KevinB Well please help then :D

Comment: Unfortunately since i'm not familiar with asp i can't comment on whether or not your asp service supports either JSONP or CORS.

Answer (score 0):

When hitting cross domain sites, with either CORS or JSONP, make sure they are both HTTP or both HTTPS.

Make sure that when HTTPS is involved, that both site's certificates have been accepted. You may need to hit the HTTPS site in another window, and accept the certificate if there is no trust relationship to the issuer.